# How to prevent a slow post form UX breaking required attribute?

Tags: html, vue.js, web-frontend

I have a form that looks like:

```html
<form method="POST">
<label>Your name:
<input name="name" required>
</label>
<input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='Sending…';">
</form>
```

The form's backend takes upto 10 seconds to respond (blockchain!), hence the disabled input to prevent multiple retries. However it then breaks the required validation and users can send in empty payloads.

Any tips how to prevent this using Vanilla or maybe VueJS?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Using Vuejs you can try :

1. `@submit.prevent="action"` in form tag instead of `onClick....`
2. add async await with try catch
3. if you want you can also disable your button in submit to be sure users can't send an empty payloads

here's a gist code : https://gist.github.com/jiyuuki/e6f8f7bb67b48014223d1561119ac2fa

Comment: Do you have something fleshed out? For example here I want to disable re-submits and show loading after form is submitted https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/zac20t5n/

Comment: I make an update to add disable enable button behavior :  https://gist.github.com/jiyuuki/e6f8f7bb67b48014223d1561119ac2fa

Comment: and in your exemple you have to probleme 1- isLoading is not declared on data scoop 2- on `<input type="submit" value="Send!" :disabled="isLoading" type="button" @click="submitFrom" />` you have a type error it's `submitForm` not `submitFrom`

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to make an API call, I simply want the form to submit but with a message like "Loading..." https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/zac20t5n/

Answer (score -1):

Try to control the button with a data property like below.

```js
export default {
  name: 'Form',
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async submitForm() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      await this.form.submit(); // Assuming this is where you make the time taking call
      this.disabled=true;
      this.value='Sending…';
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form method="POST">
  <label>Your name:
<input name="name" required>
</label>
  <input  
  :disabled="isLoading"
  type="button" 
  @click="submitFrom">
</form>
```

Reset the isLoading to false after the response reaches.

Comment: Do you have something fleshed out? For example here I want to disable re-submits and show loading after form is submitted https://jsfiddle.net/kaihendry/zac20t5n/